# Canvas : Difference between pixel values

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I test if the pixel value at a point and another point are different in an image rendered on a canvas ??
Can I get a numerical difference between the pixel value at two different locations, say pixelat(x,y)-pixelat(x1,y1) = any number ??

I need to check difference between adjacent pixel values, and do some operation when the difference goes beyond a certain value..

Comment: What do you consider more different: RGB of (200, 200, 200) versus (200, 200, 0), or RGB of (200, 200, 200) versus (130, 130, 130)?

Comment: (200,200,200) vs (130,130,130)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a pixel

```
function getPixel(x,y){
    var data = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
    return {
       r : data[0], // pixel RGBA values
       g : data[1],
       b : data[2],
       a : data[3],
       raw : new Uint32Array(data.buffer)[0], // 32bit pixel value
    };
}
if(getPixel(10,10).raw !== getPixel(100,100).raw){
      // pixels are different
}
```